# How do I use fprintf correctly to print out a matrix? Currently printing out flipped

Tags: matlab, printf

```
                data = [ xData ; yData ; segmentID ] ;
                % Write the data to file; x values in first column,
                % y in second, segment ID in third
                fprintf( trialFid, '%6.0f \t %6.0f \t %6.0f\n', data ) ;
```

In the above block of code, I have a matrix called data which consists of three columns. However, when I try to use the fprintf function it seems to print out the data from each column going down each column instead of across each row in the 3 columns as intended. I have tried removing the ;'s when i build the data matrix and it does not help. I am not too familiar with fprintf so I'm not sure if maybe my syntax is wrong. Can anyone provide any specific input on what's going wrong for me here?

Comment: Matlab reads the matrices in column-major order: down, then across. Try using `data.'` (transpose matrix) as input to `fprintf`

Comment: Thank you Luis. That did the trick.